# Check if any list items are in a string

Tags: python, list, class, assert

I have created a class that checks if any item of the list *self._name* is in the string *song1*. I use assert to check if it is True. If I change assert with print, I get that the result is None, which is why I the assert does not work. It should come out as True, but I am unsure what I am doing wrong.

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, artist, title):
        self._artist = artist
        self._title = title
            
    def checkArtist(self, name):
        self._name = name.split() #split to list since just a first name or last name is allowed
        any(artistname in self._artist for artistname in self._name)

def main_program():
    song1 = Song("Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper", "Shallow")

    #test, should return True for both asserts since the first is an exact match and the second contains "Gaga"
    assert(song1.checkArtist("Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper"))
    assert(song1.checkArtist("Lord Gaga"))
main_program()
```

It works when I isolate it outside the class. I am not too familiar with using classes, so I might have done something wrong with the class.

```
song2="Lady Gaga and Bradley Cooper"

name2="Lord Gaga"
name2=name2.split()

any(namecheck in song2 for namecheck in name2) #returns True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Song:
    def __init__(self, artist, title):
        self._artist = artist
        self._title = title
            
    def checkArtist(self, name):
        return any(artistname in self._artist for artistname in name.split())
```

You need to return your boolean value!

Comment: Thanks! I see that if I assert just "a" that I get a True as well. I would want it to be False, so maybe *any* is wrong for me to use here?

Comment: @torkestativ That's because "a" is in the artist name "LAdy GAgA and...". You might want to split also `self._artist` if you want to check only entire words (and not substrings)